# Unable to cast COM object (Delphi XE7 - Delphi Berlin incompatibility)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, delphi-10.1-berlin

I installed Delphi Berlin recently. Didn't worked so I uninstalled it same day. 
Now my Delphi XE7 stopped working. I get this error when I try to compile anything, and I don't know how to fix it.

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'Borland.Studio.Interop.IInteropMessageService'. This operation
>   failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the
>   interface with IID '{FF877130-F96F-3885-9A3E-3093A3C1D831}' failed due
>   to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))

The error is just like shown above. No source file is mentioned.

---

I already tried to use the 'fix' provided by Embarcadero but their tool won't work:

```
C:\Delphi\Delphi XE7\bin>tregsvr -t Borland.Studio.Interop.tlb
Embarcadero Turbo Register Server(32) -- COM Server Registration utility.
Version 1.3  Copyright (c) 1997-2010 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.

Type library name: C:\Delphi\Delphi XE7\bin\Borland.Studio.Interop.tlb
Type library GUID: {F939BACD-3FD5-437A-833F-BA3535A45966}

Error: Error accessing the OLE registry
```

FIX (suggested by @rruz): the utility above needs to be run under "Admin" (elevated) permissions. Thanks @RRuz.

Comment: Contact the vendor for support. Or try a web search.

Comment: We all know how fast is Embarcadero in answering support questions. Usually somebody will point to the cause of error within hours on StackOverflow. It could take over one-two week to get this fixed with embarcadero.

Comment: Amazing that you asked before searching though.

Comment: @david - you mean the 'tregsvr -t Borland.Studio.Interop.tlb' trick? Won't work. It gives me "Error: Error accessing the OLE registry"

Comment: Are you running the command `tregsvr -t Borland.Studio.Interop.tlb` from an elevated cmd.exe?

Comment: Thanks @Rruz. I will accept your answer if you post it.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. All it took was a websearch. Took me 10 seconds.

Comment: Have some problem, moved Delphi installation to different folder, then used migration wizard to solve this movement, not sure if that has something to do with it, other correctly installed Delphi installations have same problem. Tried trick above, now it goes a bit further but says error loading type library.... etc .... HRESULT: 0x80029C4A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open a command prompt as admin.
2. Go to the folder where your current
   Delphi version is installed (example "c:\Delphi\Sydney\bin")
3. Run "tregsvr -t Borland.Studio.Interop.tlb"

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, but it was a bit worse.

I also had to register this type library using the following command. Run this with elevated rights:

```
tregsvr -t Borland.Studio.ToolsAPI.tlb
```

Probably caused by moving Delphi installation to a different folder, originally installed in wrong folder, migration wizard solves some of it but apparently not all, now renaming works again.

Machine a bit sluggish, probably caused by process monitor still running, fortunately the new version this tool worked, which allowed me to find this problem.

This tool shows all registry keys queried... and this particular tool popped-up as "name not found".

I did it as follows:

1. Enable capture events
2. Clear screen.
3. Very quickly go to refactor-rename

Immediately stop capture events.

Then analyze log ;)

Comment: Tried this, but this answer mentions the wrong TLB (for this situation). It should be `tregsvr -t Borland.Studio.Interop.tlb`. I can imagine the other tlb's need (re) registering in other situations, though.